# How do i get a list (in txt file) of every computer on the domain without being a domain admin?

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, domain

I am trying to get a list of every computer. we have a catalog but we had a lot of renaming and moving that nobody documented. (i know we renamed them right, just nobody put it on paper)

I need a way the requires the least amount of privileges (so I can do it) or a trusted way i can give to the domain admin to run and be able to get that list from.

(I have some administrator rights but nothing close to domain admin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally normal users can browse the AD tree. If you have admin rights on your computer one of the easiest ways would be to install the Active Directory module for PowerShell. Then you open PowerShell by clicking Start, Run and type in `PowerShell`. After that type in:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

Then if all you want is the computer names, type in something similar to this:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like 'Windows 7*'} | Select Name | Export-Csv -Path C:\ADComputers.csv
```

Mind you, this will dump all computers in AD to a CSV file. If your environment is large this could take awhile.

Comment: Thank you! that worked! but it shows everything even the servers, is there a way to just Windows 7 machines?

Comment: @R_bow93 Added the filter you are looking for into the answer.